# Tomcat can't connect to mariadb when we deployed the java-web project in centos7

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mariadb, tomcat7

When i start the web project in IDEA, all is well, including the connection to the mariadb. But, when i put the output file(war) to the /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ and restart the tomcat service with the command "systemctl restart tomcat". Open the firefox and Enter the website "localhost:8080/online". When i input the account and the password, the browser throw an no pointer exception which means i can't connect to the mariadb.
  Why and how can i deal with this problem?

Environment:

```
$ uname -a
Linux bogon 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
$ tomcat version
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
Server built:   Mar 12 2019 10:11:36 UTC
Server number:  7.0.76.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_212-b04
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Tomcat Status:

```
$ systemctl status tomcat
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since 二 2019-09-03 09:25:46 CST; 6s ago
 Main PID: 31464 (java)
    Tasks: 46
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           └─31464 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -classpath /usr/share/tomcat/bin...
```

MariaDB Status:

```
# systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since 二 2019-09-03 07:15:24 CST; 2h 28min ago
  Process: 17937 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17905 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17936 (mysqld_safe)
    Tasks: 20
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           ├─17936 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
           └─18112 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysq...

9月 03 07:15:20 bogon systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
9月 03 07:15:20 bogon mariadb-prepare-db-dir[17905]: Database MariaDB is pro...
9月 03 07:15:20 bogon mariadb-prepare-db-dir[17905]: If this is not the case...
9月 03 07:15:20 bogon mysqld_safe[17936]: 190903 07:15:20 mysqld_safe unkno...'
9月 03 07:15:20 bogon mysqld_safe[17936]: 190903 07:15:20 mysqld_safe Loggi....
9月 03 07:15:21 bogon mysqld_safe[17936]: 190903 07:15:21 mysqld_safe Start...l
9月 03 07:15:24 bogon systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

webapps:

```
# cd /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/
# ll
总用量 19880
drwxr-xr-x. 4 tomcat tomcat     4096 9月   3 07:35 online
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root   20350442 9月   3 07:34 online.war
```

Tomcat Log Information : (/var/log/tomcat)

```
# cat localhost.2019-09-03.log
九月 03, 2019 7:17:51 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
九月 03, 2019 7:17:52 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
九月 03, 2019 7:18:06 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
严重: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/online] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bright.spring.dao.LoginDao.login(LoginDao.java:20)
    at bright.spring.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2538)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

LoginDao.java

```java
package bright.spring.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.*;
import bright.spring.jdbc.JDBC;
import bright.spring.pojo.User;

public class LoginDao {
    /**/
    Map<String,String> u = new HashMap<>();
    /**/
    ResultSet rs = null;
    public Map<String,String> login(User user){
        try {
            Connection conn = JDBC.getConnection();
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();//LoginDao.java:20
            if(user.getIdentity().equals("student")){
                rs = s.executeQuery("select * from student where username ='"+user.getUsername()+"' and password ='"+user.getPassword()+"'");
                if(rs.next()){
                    u.put("name",rs.getString("studentName") );
                }else{
                    u.put("name","isnull" );
                }
            }else if(user.getIdentity().equals("teacher")){
                rs = s.executeQuery("select * from teacher where username ='"+user.getUsername()+"' and password ='"+user.getPassword()+"'");
                if(rs.next()){
                    u.put("name",rs.getString("teacherName") );
                }else{
                    u.put("name","isnull" );
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return u;
    }
}
```

Class JDBC:

```java
package bright.spring.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBC {
static Connection conn;

    static{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        try {
            /*conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlineexp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", "root", "ch96");*/
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/onlineexp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", "root", "ch96");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can share my experience with you. i also face same type of problem. in my situation i use tomcat, Mysql, centOS.

after long time R&D i found three problem.

- One is i use MySql 8 server. it has different driver class "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
- 2nd one is CentOS firewall dose not allowing access to the MySQL server on port 3306/tcp from host 127.0.0.1
- last one is Mysql 8 default security future. (user level privilege.)

you should check all of this issue in your case.....

Comment: Just like what you had said, the problem is the Mariadb can't be access with combination of hostname "localhost" and The port "3306". I edit the "/etc/my.cnf" file, and add  a new line "port=10086"  which about the port's information .  And then, i restart the mariadb with the command "systemctl restart mariadb". But, after i press the Enter, some warnings from selinux will appear. Follow the instruction to solve the problem which is given by the selinux, like "$sudo semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 10086" and "$sudo setsebool -P tomcat_can_network_connect_db 1"

Comment: Yes, the problem had solved though  the step which is above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to update the code for MariaDB.

**MySQL driver won't work for MariaDB.**

You have to do this below :

**The JDBC driver for MariaDB** :

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
```

**How to get the connection** :

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/onlineexp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", "root", "ch96");
```

Visit [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/) for more info.

Hope this helps you. :)